# inserting data in sql database without postback in asp.net

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

When I try to insert data using AJAX without postback it's not inserting. I wrote AJAX in ajaxinsert.aspx page and I wrote a webmethod in the same page view code (i.e ajaxinsert.aspx.cs). What is the problem?

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ajaxinsert.aspx.cs" Inherits="ajaxweb.ajaxinsert" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#insert").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                var Name = $("#name1").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "Contact.aspx/savedata",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { studentname: Name },
                    success: function () {
                        $("#divreslut").text("isnerted data");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("not inseted");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" />
            <input type="submit" id="insert" value="isnertdata" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="divreslut"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```csharp
[WebMethod]
public static void savedata(string studentname)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_savedata", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", studentname);

            //if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            //{
            con.Open();

            Int32 retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (retVal > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("inserted sucess");
            }
            //if (retVal > 0)
            //{
            //    status = true;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    status = false;
            //}
            //return status;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify below line in your above .aspx page code

```
data: { studentname: Name },
```

To

```
data: JSON.stringify({studentname: Name }),
```

Javascript Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#insert").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var Name = $("#name1").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "Contact.aspx/savedata",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({studentname: Name }),
                    success: function () {
                        $("#divreslut").text("isnerted data");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("not inseted");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: after adding data: JSON.stringify({studentname: Name }),  its not hitting web method @deepak

Comment: Could you please check your code?, I am sure It will work

Comment: am debugging my code but its not hitting  the method @deepak

Comment: ok could you tell me that both "Contact.aspx" and "ajaxinsert.aspx" in same folder or they are different sub folders?

Answer (score 0):

Save data to database without postback using jQuery ajax in ASP.NET - See more at: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/save-data-to-database-without-postback-using-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net-1108.aspx#sthash.7lXf0io7.dpuf
 Please find the below link:-

http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/save-data-to-database-without-postback-using-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net-1108.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Deepak had half of the answer.  You need to add `processData: false,` to the ajax parameters.  The correct javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#insert").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var Name = $("#name1").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Contact.aspx/savedata",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ studentname: Name }),
            processData: false,
            success: function () {
               $("#divreslut").text("inserted data");
            },
            error: function () {
               alert("not inserted");
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Without the processData: false, the ajax method attempts to convert the data to URL parameters.

BTW, the best way to debug problems with AJAX posts is by using the Network tab on the F12 Developer Tools UI in the browsers.  Using that tool, you can see that the JSON data was being converted to studentname=Bob, which should then lead you to the correct solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
Add jQuery Library:

    First we have to add jQuery library. You can download jQuery library here, or you can use following jQuery CDN.
```

- See more at: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/save-data-to-database-without-postback-using-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net-1108.aspx#sthash.7lXf0io7.dpuf